# Is there a simple group and a proper subgroup with a unique and equidistant intermediate?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a **simple** group and $H$ a proper subgroup such that there is a **unique** intermediate subgroup $K$ (i.e. $H < S < G$  implies $S=K$).

> **Question**:  Is it possible that $[G:K]=[K:H]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G=M_{11}$, $K={\rm PSL}(2,11)$, $H = 11:5$, $|G:K|=|K:H|=12$.

Comment: Thank you! Is it the smallest example ?

Comment: Note that your example (of degree $144$) checks $HgK=KgH, \forall g \in G$.

Comment: Yes it's the smallest example. Another one I found is $A_{10}$ with a subgroup of index $120$ (the setwise stabilizer of three points), which itself has a maximal subgroup of index $120$.

Comment: Interesting, it's a quite rare property, perhaps there are only finitely many examples.

Comment: My computer does not yet finish to check the double coset property for your second example. *Remark*: in such examples, the transitive permutation groups related to the two intermediate inclusions can't be isomorphic, because $G$ is simple.

Comment: I found $KgH \ne HgK$ in the second example. I just chose random $g \in G$, $k \in K$ and quickly found cases in which the images of $1$ under $g$ and under $kg$ were not in the same orbit of $K$ in its action on the right cosets of $H$.